# HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having some problem in my MVC project. Everything works fine but the Customer controller is not working correctly. It was doing good before but now it generating this error

Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Here is the code for Customer controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Vidly.Models;

namespace Vidly.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Customer
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            var customers = GetCustomers();
            return View(customers);
        }

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var customer = GetCustomers().SingleOrDefault(c => c.id == id);
            if (customer == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(customer);
        }

        private IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
        {
            return new List<Customer>
            {
                new Customer {id = 1, Name = "John Smith" },
                new Customer {id = 2, Name = "Mary Williams" }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The Index action's code in Customers's view

```
@model IEnumerable<Vidly.Models.Customer>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Customers</h2>
@if (!Model.Any())
 {
     <p>We don't have any customers yet.</p>
 }
 else
 {
     <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
         <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th>Customer</th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
             @foreach (var customer in Model)
             {
                 <tr>
                     <td>@Html.ActionLink(customer.Name, "Details", "Customers", new { id = customer.id }, null)</td>
                 </tr>
             }
         </tbody>
     </table>
 }
```

Customers's details action's view implementation

```
@model Vidly.Models.Customer
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@Model.Name</h2>
```

Comment: In your `ActionLink`, you use "Customers" as controller name (with an 's'), but it should be "Customer" (no 's'). Or, as you're linking to an action on the same controller, you can omit this parameter.

Comment: Your code looks ok. What requests you are sending? It should be like this: /Customer/Index and /Customer/Details/1

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot both of you.